# Select values from another table - too slow

Tags: php, mysql

I have a huge problem with the loading time for my query. In this case I need values from the column **hg_ft_won** (table: values) for the **home_team_id** and **away_team_id** (table: matches).

It does work as it should. It only takes really long to load. Does anyone have ideas how to improve that by having an alternative query?

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT m.home_team_name, 
       m.away_team_name, 
       m.home_team_id, 
       m.away_team_id, 
       m.starting_time, 
       m.starting_date, 
       m.match_id, 
       m.season_id, 
       m.competition_id, 
       s.season_name, 
       s.country_name, 
       s.competition_name, 

  (SELECT hg_ft_won 
   FROM `values` v 
   WHERE m.home_team_id = v.team_id 
     AND m.season_id = v.season_id ) AS hg_ft_won1, 

  (SELECT hg_ft_won 
   FROM `values` v 
   WHERE m.away_team_id = v.team_id 
     AND m.season_id = v.season_id ) AS hg_ft_won2, 

FROM matches m, 
     seasons s
WHERE m.season_id = s.id 
AND m.starting_date = '2017-02-11'");
```

*values table*

[image: values table]

*matches table*

[image: matches table]

*results from webpagetest.org*
[image: performance test]

Comment: You could start by using joins instead of sub-queries to get `hg_ft_won1` and `hg_ft_won2`. You should also check that your tables are properly indexed.

Comment: I have tried INNER JOIN but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What didn't work? Errors? Wrong result? Post that attempt as well.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  This is essentially your query:

```
SELECT . . .
       (SELECT hg_ft_won 
        FROM `values` v 
        WHERE m.home_team_id = v.team_id AND m.season_id = v.season_id
      ) AS hg_ft_won1, 
      (SELECT hg_ft_won 
       FROM `values` v 
       WHERE m.away_team_id = v.team_id AND
             m.season_id = v.season_id
      ) AS hg_ft_won2,
FROM matches m JOIN 
     seasons s
     ON m.season_id = s.id LEFT JOIN
     competition
     ON competition.id = ?.competition_id 
WHERE m.starting_date = '2017-02-11'");
```

For this query, you want indexes on:

- `matches(starting_date, season_id)`
- `seasons(id)` (probably already there)
- `competition(id)` (probably already there)
- `values(team_id, season_id, hg_ft_won)`

I don't know where `competition_id` is.  It should be added at the last key to whichever table it belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works, but it is not much faster than the one I got. The matches table has about 2.000 rows and 20 columns and the values table has 2.000 rows and 400 (yes) columns. Might that be the reason?

Comment: @vloryan . . . That is not very much data.  How much time does the query take?

Comment: It takes about 4 seconds to load. I just added results from webpagetest.org

Comment: @vloryan . . . Are you sure the bottleneck is the query and not the graphics on the screen?  What happens if you put the data into a table directly, and use that for the timing test?

Comment: I don't have one image on the page or anything else. This one query is all there is on that test page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on this query. Create the required index wherever possible.

```
    SELECT m.home_team_name, 
        m.away_team_name, 
        m.home_team_id, 
        m.away_team_id, 
        m.starting_time, 
        m.starting_date, 
        m.match_id, 
        m.season_id, 
        m.competition_id, 
        s.season_name, 
        s.country_name, 
        s.competition_name, 
        v1.hg_ft_won  AS hg_ft_won1, 
        v2.hg_ft_won  AS hg_ft_won2, 
    FROM matches m 
        INNER JOIN seasons s ON m.season_id = s.id
        LEFT JOIN `values` v1 ON m.home_team_id = v1.team_id  AND m.season_id = v1.season_id
        LEFT JOIN `values` v2 ON m.home_team_id = v2.team_id  AND m.season_id = v2.season_id
    AND m.starting_date = '2017-02-11'
```